# AngularJS 1.x and Tape JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm presently working on a very large modular web app. where the front-end is implemented using AngularJS 1.x. The project is about 2 years old and there was never any unit testing done as part of the development process. There is now a requirement to add unit testing for at least 85% of the Angular codebase. The general consensus seems to be: "Use Jasmine/Karma or Mocha/Chai/Sinon" for unit testing.

My concern after looking at the usual testing libraries is the amount of work that will need to be put in for data mocks and unit testing in general. It seems excessive and almost as bad as re-developing the application. Recently I've also read a couple of articles regarding the general overhead of unit testing with sophisticated testing libraries like Jasmine (see: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/why-i-use-tape-instead-of-mocha-so-should-you-6aa105d8eaf4#.1bzhv0q1f)

The part about using Tape JS to test got me wondering whether that is easily done in Angular 1.x. I've very new to unit testing and wanted to find out whether anyone has done unit testing using Tape with Angular 1.x? Is this possible?

Thoughts on pros/cons/experiences with Tape and generally unit testing in Angular, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I have never tried to use Tape with AngularJS, but I like the idea. I write my unit tests in Jasmine/Karma, and it is indeed a ton of work to mock. I try to reduce the amount of work by mocking as little as possible to get my tests to pass. Part of this is making sure the functions I write are pure. I also only test with $componentController. I don't compile any html in my unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment.

I think the reason everyone uses Jasmine is that they want to test their code through the AngularJS interface, and that requires a test harness.

For example - let's say you are writing a test for a component. You will have to bootstrap the component's angular.module. You'll also have to create an instance of the component's controller through $componentController. And if the controller requires any dependencies, you'll have to make sure those dependencies also have their angular.module bootstrapped.

Jasmine does all this great.

However, Jasmine can very quickly become unwieldy. It introduces all sorts of global variables. There is a ton of repetition involved with BeforeEach. And to run your tests, you'll probably have to use Karma, which requires a lot of dependencies and is pretty darn slow.

I think you could skip all this and just use TapeJS if you were okay with testing your code as plain old javascript. I think this approach is okay for unit tests -- but for e2e tests, you should dive into jasmine/protractor.

For example, my AngularJS applications are written in Typescript with class syntax. Every component controller and service is a typescript class that is also exported. So to test with TypeJS, all you have to do is import the typescript class, create an instance of it, and voila. You now have access to all the methods (assuming they are all public), and you can test that input/output works as expected.

This should work fine for AngularJS 1.5+, but if you have an app with a lot of directives, I'm not sure how that would work.

I do hope this helps. Spending days trying to get test runners to work is the worst.

Read more:

https://ponyfoo.com/articles/testing-javascript-modules-with-tape